# How to make flex items that are also flex containers stack horizontally?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to create a horizontal menu. My understanding of flexbox is that if I want to have elements stack horizontally, I should apply the CSS rules

```
display: flex
flex-direction: row;
```

However, in the following page, the boxes stack vertically

```css
div#navcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

div.navitem {
  color: #292929;
  height: 45px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: 292929;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="navcontainer">
    <div class="navitem"><a href="./index.html">home</a></div>
    <div class="navitem"><a href="./about.html">about</a></div>
    <div class="navitem"><a href="./services.html">services</a></div>
    <div class="navitem"><a href="./contact.html">contact</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make css flex-items which are themselves flex containers of other elements stack vertically?

Comment: Note that in your HTML you have `id="navcontainer"`, but in the CSS it's `.navcontainer`... You also have `navcontainer` set to `flex-direction: column`, which stacks items vertically.

Comment: the first error was introduced by someone else's edit to split the css and html into separate chunks. The second error was my own--the last thing I tried before asking on SO was seeing if flex-direction: column would paradoxically work.

Comment: Actually no. the first error was in my original question and is in fact the cause of the problem: I had miswritten my selector to refer to the *class* `navcontainer` when I should have been referring to the **id**. and so my `display: flex` was just never getting applied at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `display: flex` to `#navcontainer`. You can also get it without flexbox. Use `display: inline-block` and percentage values for boxes.

Comment: With `display: inline-block`, the items will wrap when the screen gets too small, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal flex direction is a default direction, so `flex-direction: row` is superfluous. Right now you have a horizontal list which will contain vertical flex boxes.

```
#navcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.navitem {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: apologies--I meant to have `flex-direction: row` in on the #navcontainer.